# Magento multistore redirect just one domain.com including path to https

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect, https, multistore

I have a multistore setup on magento with multiple domains.
But I want just one specific store/domain to have https, and redirect all non https urls for that domain to https. Including the whole path.

For example all urls in this list to https://www.

Source urls:
    http:// webwinkel.nl/willekeurige-categorienaam 
    www. webwinkel.nl/willekeurige-categorienaam
    http:// www.webwinkel.nl/willekeurige-categorienaam
    https:// webwinkel.nl/willekeurige-categorienaam

Target url:
    https:// www.webwinkel.nl/willekeurige-categorienaam

I use this for a single store, and in that case it works perfect.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But for a multistore this doesn't work, because it will redirect every store domain to https, but I want https only for one specific store.

## Edit

@itoctopus: Thanx for your reply!

This works for www.webwinkel.nl.
But not for the other domains on the same multistore.

For example I have www.webwinkel.nl, www.webwinkel2.nl and www.webwinkel3.nl.
With your code, they all will redirect to www.webwinkel.nl.

This is my whole htaccess now:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)webwinkel.nl [NC] 
RewriteRule . - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)webwinkel.nl [NC] 
RewriteRule . - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:webwinkel] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)webwinkel2.nl [NC] 
RewriteRule . - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)webwinkel2.nl [NC] 
RewriteRule . - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:webwinkel2] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)webwinkel3.nl [NC] 
RewriteRule . - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)webwinkel3.nl [NC] 
RewriteRule . - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:webwinkel3] 


# First condition - redirect non-www to www for all domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Second condition - redirect HTTP to HTTPS for a particular domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^webwinkel\.nl$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.webwinkel.nl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your `.htaccess` file to ensure that only a particular domain gets redirected to `https://www`. The first condition is to handle redirection from non-www to www for all other domains. The second condition is for redirecting your domain to https.

```
RewriteEngine On
# First condition - redirect non-www to www for all domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Second condition - redirect HTTP to HTTPS for a particular domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^webwinkel\.nl$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.webwinkel.nl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Any news on this subject, am looking for the same thing?